# swift language version 3.2 missing

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I noticed that the Swift 3.2 is missing from the Swift Language Version. I have pods in my project that need to run on 3.2. I'm using Xcode 10.0 and Swift 4.2... From my research i should be able to change the Swift Language Version in the pod file but my attempts to do so have been unsuccessful. Is there any way to get 3.2 to run in my pod files in Xcode 10?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCBNl.png)

Here is what i tried in the pod file

```
 # force the sub specs in the array below to use swift version 3.2
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if ['PromiseKit'].include? target.name
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What happens when you just set the version to `'3'`?

Comment: The application build fails... I just tried building it on 4.2 and that worked. This is my first time working with cocoa pods i'm guessing they are updated so i don't need to use older language